# The right way to run a Node.js app with nginx

Tags: multithreading, node.js, nginx

I have written a web app with node.js using:

- express
- socket.io
- redis for the session store and for some caching stuff
- mysql for persistant data

This works well in standalone and I now would like to make it work in "production" mode.
Actually I would like to have nginx in front redirecting requests to a node server running.

For now, I use a single physical server (i5 - 4 cores) for everything, but this can change in the future (so maybe another only for mysql, etc.)

In this case:

- Should I use nginx load balancing between upstreams? (i.e. running my app with different ports)

The nginx config would be something like this:

```
upstream my_app {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    server 127.0.0.1:3001;
    server 127.0.0.1:3002;
}
```

Then, what is the proper way to run node as a service so I can easily restart it? 
I can create a simple script myself (handling start/stop/restart, ...) but maybe can I use something already available?

- Should I use node clustering?

My app currently works in a single thread, but from what I have read I know I can multithread or fork my process with solutions such as pm2/nodemon/forever but not sure which one fits the best.

I have just tried pm2 which works well clustering or forking the node process, just not sure this is the way to go with nginx.

Thanks,

Comment: For the part about running you app as a service take a look at this http://dailyjs.com/2011/03/07/node-deployment/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what you are asking, but I will give it a shot.

1. You should be using the cluster module in order to get full use of your machine. If you have 4 cores, using cluster will spawn 4 processes of your application; 1 for each core. This is the preferred approach to running your application 4 different times, listening on different ports, with nginx load balancing between the instances. The other plus about the cluster module is that it will restart children that die.
2. As I mentioned in 1, the cluster module will balance requests amongst processes on a single machine, so you would only need 1 upstream in nginx. If you were too add a second (or third) server, you should add an upstream for each server. Again, only one upstream per server, as the cluster module should delegate from there.

If this is not quite what you were asking, my apologies.

Comment: Sorry if this was not so clear as I was asking different pieces of advice. Yes this exactly answers my different interrogations! I actually wanted to be sure to do the right thing. I'll take a look at the cluster module.